# Custom conditional configuration for Gradle project

Tags: gradle

Having an extract from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/build.gradle:

```
ext {
  isDevBuild = {
    gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(developerBuild)
  }
}

task developerBuild {
  description = 'Builds distributions and runs pre-checkin checks'
  group = 'build'
  dependsOn testedDists
}
```

When I used this approach to create custom configuration in my project I discovered that:

```
isDevBuild === true
```

i.e. it's always true because task 'developerBuild' is inside my build.gradle project, and hence in graph. They have a couple of "different" configs (isCIBuild, isCommitBuild, isFinalReleaseBuild, ...) so I suppose I got something wrong here.

Can someone explain how to make this configs conditional based on some external parameter?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`taskGraph.hasTask()` tells if a task is in the task *execution* graph, that is whether it will get executed. Because the task execution graph is only created after the configuration phase, this method has to be called from a `whenReady` callback (or in the execution phase):

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(developerBuild)) { 
        // do conditional configuration
    }
}
```

To make this more readable, we can introduce a new method:

```
def onlyFor(task, config) {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(task)) { 
            project.configure(project, config)
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can write:

```
onlyFor(developerBuild) { ... }
onlyFor(ciBuild) { ... }
```

Another, simpler way to solve this problem is to check whether a particular task name is contained in `gradle.startParameter.taskNames`. However, this has two limitations: First, it compares task *names*, which can make a difference in multi-project builds. Second, it will only find tasks that have been specified directly (e.g. on the command line), but not dependencies thereof.

PS.: In your code, `isDevBuild` always holds because a (non-null) closure is `true` according to Groovy truth. (In contrast to `isDevBuild()`, `isDevBuild` won't call the closure.)

Comment: Going back to assertion from the "Building and Testing with Gradle" book: knowledge of Groovy is not plus - it's a must to start to work with Gradle. Thanks for your help. Will check it later today.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a must to get started, but it's necessary to implement advanced solutions like this one. (A simple alternative which requires less Groovy knowledge is to switch between different configurations based on a system property.) Then again, much of this code could be written in Java style (with anonymous inner classes and such), or literally in Java if you moved it into a plugin. The real challenge in this particular case is to understand the Gradle side of things: the task graph API, configuration vs. execution phase, etc.

Comment: Your solution works well. Thanks a lot. For the note you put in P.S. : I can not directly call `isDevBuild()` when I execute Gradle build with `ciBuild jar` for example (and I can not use both configs in same time) - although you showed that I can call closure only for educational purposes.

Comment: Thanks to take a look at question at SO: not all lead developers commit their time for community support.