# Gradle - different task use different parameter

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have two tasks,task_1 should compress png files and task_2 should not compress png files,so i want to add an parameter to control it.

```
project.ext.set("compressPngs",  1);
task taskCompressPngs(type:Exec){
    commandLine "myshell.sh"
    args compressPngs
}

task task_1(dependsOn:'taskCompressPngs'){}
task task_2(dependsOn:'taskCompressPngs'){}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(task_1)) 
    {
        compressPngs=1
    }
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(task_2)) 
    {
        compressPngs=0
    }
}
```

But when i run task_1 or task_2，in task 'taskCompressPngs', 'compressPngs' passed to my script 'myshell.sh' always be 1, why? how to solve it?

Comment: Why does task_2 dependsOn taskCompressPngs when it should not compress?

Comment: the whole task graph is that: task_2(task_1) -> task 'osbuild' -> sign -> package ->  taskCompressPngs, '->' means depends on. I just want the task graph to be clear.

Comment: Maybe moving 'args compressPngs' within a doLast{} will do the trick. That way it is set **after** configuration. But as the intelligent @PeterNiederwieser says; conditional configuration is rarely a good solution.

Comment: I defer to Peter N's advice, but the following link is likely useful if you are adamant on trying it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554950/custom-conditional-configuration-for-gradle-project

Comment: I have tried it,but not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's probably best to take the [advice of @PeterNiederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21783576/1174467) and use two separate tasks, but if you really don't think you can, here are a couple other options that should work.

### 1) Check Gradle startParameter

Configure your reusable task based on which task is passed to gradle on the command line.

```
task taskCompressPngs(type: Exec) {
    def compressPngs = 1
    if(gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString().toLowerCase().contains("task_2")) compressPngs = 0
    commandLine "myshell.sh $compressPngs".tokenize()
}
```

This gives you a variable to use (`gradle.startParameter.taskNames`) that is available at configuration-time.

Here we change compressPngs to 0 ***only if*** task_2 is specified on the command line when running gradle.

I.E. `gradlew task_1` will run `myshell.sh 1`, but `gradlew task_2` (or even `gradlew task_1 task_2`) will run `myshell.sh 0`.

This logic could also be applied to a project property outside of the taskCompressPngs task - if, for example, you wanted to change other tasks too.

Again, this only works if "task_2" is specified in the command used to run gradle.

### 2) Use DefaultExecAction instead of Exec task

Instead of using a task of type `Exec`, you could write a custom task and check the taskGraph in it.

```
task taskCompressPngs << {
    def compressPngs = 1
    if(gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(two)) compressPngs = 2
    org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction e = new org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction(getServices().get(org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileResolver.class))
    e.commandLine("myshell.sh $compressPngs".tokenize())
    e.execute()
}
```

This is just moves your existing logic from configuration-time to execution-time.

This requires the use of "internal" Gradle classes (which is bad), but it gives you a little more flexibility in how/when the shell command is run.

Note that these solutions were checked against Gradle 1.7 and Gradle 1.11.

Answer (score 2):

`taskCompressPngs` gets configured before the configuration value is changed. Conditional configuration is rarely a good solution. A better approach is to declare two `Exec` tasks.